# Can I create custom reformat code in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Can I create custom reformat code?

**When I press Ctrl + Alt + L in themes file the result will be like this**

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Test" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**I want it like this one**

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Test" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to acheive? Have you looked into Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | XML | Android | **Use custom formatting settings for Android XML files** options? Or Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | XML | Other | **Keep blank lines** and **Keep line breaks**.